# Voucher Error When Trying to Redeem

Tags: devdemon, subscriptions

[image]

Seems to work when I add the missing 'billing_at' column to the database table.

Maybe it was intended to be 'created_at'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug has been fixed internally and an update will be released very soon.